# How to config PoolingOption in Spark join

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I'm using Structured Streaming 2.4 and trying to write to one node Cassandra with foreachBatch sink like:

```
foreachBatch { (df, batchId) =>
        df
          .rdd
          .repartitionByCassandraReplica("ks", "tbl")
          .leftJoinWithCassandraTable("ks", "tbl")
          .on(SomeColumns("id"))
          .map(...)
          .toDF(...)
          .write
          .cassandraFormat("tbl", "ks")
          .mode("Append")
          .save()
```

When the df has 1 million rows, spark can write some rows to Cassandra and then throws:

```
WARN QueryExecutor: BusyPoolException ... Retrying
```

and then:

```
ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@
```

Cassandra stopped after that. So if I want to configure something like PoolingOptions, can anyone please help with some example on how to configure Datastax connector in foreachBatch sink?

Thanks

Comment: what settings for Spark connector are you using already?

Comment: I didn't set up any specific conf for C*. It works on my laptop, but fails on a EC2 node (on which I set up a local spark there).